# Merge two sorted linear graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code for a function to calculator the addition of two sorted List. Each element of List is tuple type (xi, yi) that represents graph individual (x,y) points at coordinate system.

> two input List is sorted by x value and length of A, B list may be different
>   [(Ax0, Ay0),..., (Axi, Ayi), (Axi+1, Ayi+1),, ...(Axn, Ayn)]
> [(Bx0, By0),..., (Bxi, Byi), (Bxi+1, Byi+1),, ...(Bxk, Byk)]

```
example 1:
A:[(1, 1]]=> one point: 1, at x coordinate, 0 at y coordinate
B:[(0, 0]]=> one point: 0, at x coordinate, 0 at y coordinate
=> graph_addition(A, B) == [(0,0), (1,1)] 
a line with two point (0,0) and (1,1)

example 2:
A:[(3, 3), (5,5)]=> one line at (3,3), (5,5)
B:[(4, 4), (5, 5), (10, 8)]=> 2 segment line: 
ex: graph_addition(A, B) = [(3, 3), (4, 8.0), (5, 10)] 
3 segment line with 3 point [(3, 3), (4, 8.0), (5, 10), (10, 8)]
For A when x at 4, y should be 4 based on slope calculation

example 3:
A:[(3,3), (5,5), (6,3), (7,5)]
B:[(0,0), (2,2), (4,3), (5,3), (10,2)]
explanation
when x = 0 at B line, y=0, at A line y = 0 => (0, 0)
when x = 2 at B line, y=2, at A line y = 0 => (0, 0)
when x = 4 at B line, y=3, at A line y = (5-3 / 5-3 * 4) => (4, 7)
when x = 5 at B line, y=3, at A line y = 5 => (5, 8)
when x = 6 at B line, y= (2 - 3)/(10-5) * 6, at A line y = 3 => (6, 0)
when x = 7 at B line, y= (2 - 3)/(10-5) * 7, at A line y = 5 => (7, 1.5)
when x = 10 at B line, y=3, at A line y = (5-3 / 5-3 * 4) => (4, 7)
=> [(0, 0), (2, 2), (3, 5.5), (4, 7.0), (5, 8), (6, 5.8), (7, 7.6), (10, 2)]
```

Is there a better way for me to not using bruteforce way to calculate x, y values?

```
def graph_addition(A, B):
     if not A or not B: return A or B
     res = []
     i = j = 0
     while i < len(A) and j < len(B):
         if A[i][0] < B[0][0]:
             x, y = A[i]
             i += 1
         elif B[j][0] < A[0][0]:
             x, y = B[j]
             j += 1
         elif A[i][0] < B[j][0]:
             x = A[i][0]
             y = (B[j][1] - B[j - 1][1]) / (B[j][0] - B[j - 1][0]) * (x - B[j - 1][0]) + B[j - 1][1] + A[i][1]
             i += 1
         elif A[i][0] > B[j][0]:
             x = B[j][0]
             y = (A[i][1] - A[i - 1][1]) / (A[i][0] - A[i - 1][0]) * (x - A[i - 1][0]) + A[i - 1][1] + B[j][1]
             j += 1
         else:
             x = A[i][0]
             y = A[i][1] + B[j][1]
             i += 1
             j += 1
         res.append((x, y))
     if A[i:]: res += A[i:]
     if B[j:]: res += B[j:]
     return res
```

Comment: Hello @Alee. I do not understand the intended functionality from your brief description or example. Could you edit the question to include more detail?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `yield` instead of building a list. There is no need for an explicit list.
2. At start of method `or` input with `[]` for cleaner `None` checks.
3. Move interpolation into a function. This avoid repeated code.
4. Move all the casework into the interpolation function.

```
def graph_value(L, i, x):
    if x == L[i][0]: return L[i][1]
    if i == 0: return 0
    m = (L[i][1] - L[i - 1][1]) / (L[i][0] - L[i - 1][0])
    return m * (x - L[i - 1][0]) + L[i - 1][1]

def graph_addition(A, B):
    A = A or []
    B = B or []
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(A) and j < len(B):
        x = min(A[i][0], B[j][0])
        y = graph_value(A, i, x) + graph_value(B, j, x)
        i += (x == A[i][0])
        j += (x == B[j][0])
        yield (x,y)
    yield from A[i:]
    yield from B[j:]
```

Exercise to the reader: write a version that takes in two arbitrary iterables and performs the same functionality.

Comment: nice code. totally agree yield make the code more clean and any better way for not doing the math calculation you can think of?